# Submitting/Validating in app purchases requiring Info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, ios8, xcode6

I created an in-app purchase content like i normally do in Xcode 6.0 using the in app purchase template.
When i go to validate or submit the in app purchase content, yesterday it started failing due to missing Info.plist. However in app purchase content does not have an Info.plist (should not and can not). It uses a ContentInfo.plist instead. I've tried creating an Info.plist but its impossible since in-app purchase content doesn't have the characteristics required in an info.plist.

Anyone else get this problem? How do i submit my in-app purchases now?

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem, and was able to workaround by using the separate Application Loader to upload my IAP content.

Application Loader is available in iTunes Connect; i found it under the "Resources and Help" section. Apparently it is a better-supported mechanism for uploading stuff to the iTunes store than XCode.

Comment: This worked via Application Loader. Looks like it is a but in XCode 6.0.1 (6A317). I upvoted your answer.

Comment: This issue is still present in Xcode version 6.1 (6A1052d)

Comment: Application Loader still has this limit from long long time ago:      ERROR ITMS-4162: "The total sizes of all the IAP hosted content assets exceed the limit of 5 GB" at Software/SoftwareMetadata

Comment: Present in 6.2 (Beta) as well. Anyone ever report this via the Apple bug reporter?

Comment: Still persist in 6.4. I reported around Nov 2014 with XCode 6.1, got 1 response, then closed because of duplication. I was angry that until 6.4 the problem still persists, and report it again. But I also found that using XCode 5.1.1 submissions work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

I redownloaded Xcode 5.1.1 and use the Organizer to upload in-app-purchase.